# How to extract only cetain part of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like below.I want to keep only first percentage from column 3 and 4. How can this be achieved.Any help is appreciated

```
Metric Group  Metric Type       Tue23rd                      Week24                      
Productive    % Available     83.2%Best Class:D7-92.6%     92.6%Best Class:WD-96.21%
Productive    % Available     85.2%Best Class:A7-98.6%     92.6%Best Class:LD-95.21%
Productive    % Available     89.2%Best Class:D7-94.6%     92.6%Best Class:WD-93.21%
```

Expected output is some thing like

```
Metric Group    Metric Type       Tue23rd          Week24                      
Productive     % Available        83.2%             92.6%
Productive     % Available        85.2%             92.6%
Productive     % Available        89.2%             92.6%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `pd.Series.str.extract` method using regex:

```
df["Tue23rd"].str.extract("([0-9\.%]+)Best")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pattern = '^([\d\.%]+)'

for col in df.columns[2:]:
    df[col] = df[col].str.extract(pattern)[0]
```

Output:

```
  Metric Group  Metric Type Tue23rd Week24
0   Productive  % Available   83.2%  92.6%
1   Productive  % Available   85.2%  92.6%
2   Productive  % Available   89.2%  92.6%
```

Comment: Can we loop through this if we have more than 2 columns because i have 16 columns in actual dataframe

Comment: It throws an error anomalous backslash in string:'\d'

Answer (score 0):

Please use this; `str.replace()` any `alphanumeric` and `non digits` that immediately follow a `digit%`. Sligthly faster than @Quang Hoang

```
 df=df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('((?<=\d[%])([\w\D]+))',''))



 Metric Group  Metric Type Tue23rd Week24
0   Productive  % Available   83.2%  92.6%
1   Productive  % Available   85.2%  92.6%
```

Comment: Hi! What is this part of the regex doing? 
`(?<=\`

Comment: That is  positive look behind assertion. For instance (?<+=x)y matches y only if x is to its left

Comment: This throws the same error like @Quang Hoang solution.anomalous backslash in string:'\d'.String constant might be missing an r prefix

Answer (score 0):

You can also split on `%` and just grab the first group:
I am not sure if there is a way to keep the separator when splitting in Pandas

```
df.iloc[:, 2:]  = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: x.str.split('%').str[0] + '%')


Metric Group  Metric Type Tue23rd Week24
0   Productive  % Available   83.2%  92.6%
1   Productive  % Available   85.2%  92.6%
2   Productive  % Available   89.2%  92.6%
```

Comment: did that help at all?

Comment: No, this throws an error. AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values!'

Comment: I sincerely didnt expect that to happen. It is working for me on different pandas versions. please try .replace(r'((?<=\d[%])([\w\D]+))',''). r indicates that the string is to be treated as a raw string, it literally removes python string parsing aspect.

Comment: .replace gives same error.   df1 =final_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'((?<=\d[%])([\w\D]+))',''))